# Python, sorting a list of dicts with list in the value

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, nested

I have been attempting to loop through and sort a list containing dicts with a list in the value(SIDE_1 & SIDE_2). I want to sort based on the 0 index of each list in the dict. EX:{'monday': [3, 2]}, value 3 should be sorting criteria.

I have tried using the list sort() method but the best outcome I get is two None values (SIDE_1=None then SIDE_2=None). I have also tried the dict sorted() method which seems to be closer to my solution but when I pass my sorter() function as the key I always get TypeError: string indices must be integers.

I have tested my sorter() function by printing and I get the values I want to sort my list on however, when I attempt to use sort() or sorted() the error occurs.

outcome should be:

```
SIDE_1: thursday, monday, wednesday, tuesday
SIDE_2: may, march, april, june
```

**MY CODE:**

```
example = {'TOP': {'SIDE_1': [{'monday': [3, 2]}, {'tuesday': [1, 2]}, {'wednesday': [2, 1]}, {'thursday': [4, 0]}], 'SIDE_2': [{'march': [2, 1]}, {'april': [1, 2]}, {'may': [3, 3]}, {'june': [0, 3]}]}}


def sorter(obj):
    for o in obj:
        for h in o:
            return o[h][0] # when I use print to test what value I am getting it works correctly. however, i do get None at the end of each loop.

for top in example:
    for side in example[top]:
        x = example[top][side]
        print(sorted(x, key=sorter)) # if I just do print(sorter(x)) it returns the expected value(s)
```

**outcome: TypeError: string indices must be integers. --- return o[h][0]**

also when I just print(sorter(x)) inside the for loop I get:
3
1
2
4
None
2
1
3
0
None

Why do I get None at the end of each loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
example = {
    "TOP": {
        "SIDE_1": [
            {"monday": [3, 2]},
            {"tuesday": [1, 2]},
            {"wednesday": [2, 1]},
            {"thursday": [4, 0]},
        ],
        "SIDE_2": [
            {"march": [2, 1]},
            {"april": [1, 2]},
            {"may": [3, 3]},
            {"june": [0, 3]},
        ],
    }
}

for k1, v1 in example.items():
    for k2, v2 in v1.items():
        v1[k2] = sorted(v2, key=lambda k: [*k.values()][0][0], reverse=True)

# pretty print the output
from pprint import pprint
pprint(example)
```

Prints:

```py
{'TOP': {'SIDE_1': [{'thursday': [4, 0]},
                    {'monday': [3, 2]},
                    {'wednesday': [2, 1]},
                    {'tuesday': [1, 2]}],
         'SIDE_2': [{'may': [3, 3]},
                    {'march': [2, 1]},
                    {'april': [1, 2]},
                    {'june': [0, 3]}]}}
```

Comment: Very grateful @ Andrej thank you. could you briefly explain [*k.values()][0][0]?

Comment: @CornellForeman For example, for `k={'thursday': [4, 0]}` the `[*k.values()][0][0]` gets the first value (the list `[4, 0]`) and then the first element (`4`). `[*k.values()]` is synonym for `list(k.values())`

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, it'll give an error. if you add 3 print statements in your code -

```
def sorter(obj):
    for o in obj:
        for h in o:
            print(f'h is {h}')
            print(f'o is {o}')
            print(f'obj is {obj}')
            return o[h][0]
```

It'll print -

```
h is m
o is monday
obj is {'monday': [3, 2]}
```

Now, you're trying to return o[h][0] -
place the value of h - o['m'][0] -> here o is monday. Did you saw the issue?  if you do o[0] then you'll get 'm'. But o['m'][0] will give you the error.

I guess you wanna use the 1st element in the list as a key. Here's the code for that if that's what you need.

```
def sorter(obj):
    for o in obj:
        return obj[o][0] # when I use print to test what value I am getting it works correctly. however, i do get None at the end of each loop.
```

Comment: obj is NOT {'monday': [3, 2]} it is the list [...] containing the {'monday': [3, 2]} dict and 3 other {...}'s. obj = 'SIDE_1' or 'SIDE_2' from the example variable.

Comment: It's not list in your second function you're taking 1 element from the list and passing that object to function sorter. :)

Comment: oh ok you are referring to how sorted() is viewing what I am trying to do in my sorter(). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
def sorter(obj):
  for o in obj:        # o == 'monday'
    for h in o:        # h == 'm'
      return o[h][0]   # o[h][0] == 'monday'['m'][0]
```

Second:

```
print(sorter(x))    # this means 'obj' in sorter(obj) above receives [{'monday': ...
```

That isn't the same as what sorted is doing, which is:

```
for value in x:    # sorted(x, key=sorter) calls your sorter() like this...
   sorter(value)   # ... and sorts based on the return values of those calls.
```

I don't know how you're getting None.  It isn't happening for me in Python v3.9.2.